# Brief detail on hosts file

Tags: lamp, localhost, hosts

Can somebody explain what does this mean? Explanation to each line will be helpful. I have mentioned some of my queries in comments too.

1. 127.0.0.1 localhost              //According to @Dave, it's machine ip.
2. 127.0.1.1 dell-Inspiron-342      //  then what is this ip of?

   The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
3. ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
4. fe00::0 ip6-localnet
5. ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
6. ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
7. ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: For a very thorough explanation of a /etc/hosts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

Comment: Sorry pal. It's lamp. I have just tagged xamp so that I can get attention of more people. It will be helpful if you answer my question.

Comment: It's not that I hate xamp. It's just that I like lamp :). Thanks for proving details on hosts through wikipedia. But I was hoping to know details on each line of host not about host. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: @Rinzwind I think you can help me. I have numbered above line. Can you explain what is work of 1-7?

Comment: is this enough information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 is the IP address for local machine. That means the machine you are working on and it is the same for **all** of us (we all have this). This line should not be messed with.

127.0.1.1. [Section 10.4 of the debian manual](http://qref.sourceforge.net/quick/ch-gateway.en.html):

> Some software (e.g., GNOME) expects the system hostname to be resolvable to an IP address with a canonical fully qualified domain name. This is really improper because system hostnames and domain names are two very different things; but there you have it. In order to support that software, it is necessary to ensure that the system hostname can be resolved. Most often this is done by putting a line in /etc/hosts containing some IP address and the system hostname. If your system has a permanent IP address then use that; otherwise use the address 127.0.1.1.

Is added due to this bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=719621

Both of these IPs are IPv4. Since the world is running out of IP addresses there is also IPv6. Where IPv4 uses 4 numbers from 0 to 255 (roughly; so 2**32 permutations) IPv6 addresses are 128 bits long (so 2*128 permutations) used in 8 groups of 4 hexadecimal digits.

These ...

```
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

are all IPv6 versions. ::1 is the IPv6 version of 127.0.0.1 so also means local host.

These are [multicast addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address):

> **Well-known IPv6 multicast addresses**

```
Address     Description
ff02::1     All nodes on the local network segment
ff02::2     All routers on the local network segment
ff02::5     OSPFv3 All SPF routers
ff02::6     OSPFv3 All DR routers
ff02::8     IS-IS for IPv6 routers
ff02::9     RIP routers
ff02::a     EIGRP routers
ff02::d     PIM routers
ff02::16    MLDv2 reports (defined in RFC 3810)
ff02::1:2   All DHCP servers and relay agents on the local network segment (defined in RFC 3315)
ff02::1:3   All LLMNR hosts on the local network segment (defined in RFC 4795)
ff05::1:3   All DHCP servers on the local network site (defined in RFC 3315)
ff0x::c     Simple Service Discovery Protocol
ff0x::fb    Multicast DNS
ff0x::101   Network Time Protocol
ff0x::108   Network Information Service
ff0x::114   Used for experiments
```

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/hosts file tells a browser which IP a domain, or hosts has, without asking DNS-Services.

Normally LAMPP and co. are used to setup up servers on your local machine. The ip 127.0.0.1 ist known as any machine itself - so, if you're setting up the site lampas.tld on your local machine, add the following line to your file /etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1 www.lampas.tld lampas.tld

Comment: And what does this mean?
127.0.1.1   dell-Inspiron-342
 Isn't this ip of this machine itself? If not what is this IP pointing at?